# How to compare managed objects in different contexts?

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, concurrency, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a class where I keep references to a set of `NSManagedObject` in an array. Such managed objects belong to which I call my `mainContext`, that is associated to main thread.

To update such objects, I call several web services, and I create new managed objects with the information I get from them. I insert those new objects in a context I call `privateContext` that is associated to a private queue. This context has its own separated Core Data stack, it is not child of the `mainContext`. I do this to avoid blocking the main thread while performing updates.

In the same class where I have the array of managed objects in the `mainContext` (`self.entities`), I have another array to keep the references of the managed objects in the `privateContext` (`self.tempEntities`). My intention is to compare the managed objects in both arrays and make the changes I could need to make to the objects in `mainContext`:

```
- (void)manageEntitiesUpdate
{
   if ((self.tempEntities != nil) && (self.entities != nil)) {
       if (self.tempEntities.count > 0) {

           NSMutableArray *toDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
           NSMutableArray *toModify = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

           for (MyEntity *tempEntity in self.tempEntities) {

               if (![tempEntity.isValid boolValue]) {
                   [toDelete addObject:tempEntity.idEntity];
               }

               for (MyEntity *entity in self.entities) {
                   if ([tempEntity.idEntity integerValue] == [entity.idEntity integerValue]) {
                       [toModify addObject:tempEntity.idEntity];
                       break;
                   }
               }
           }

           if (toDelete.count > 0) {
               // Get main context
               NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext = [CoreDataStack getMainContext];

               if (mainContext != nil) {
                   for (NSNumber *idEntity in toDelete) {

                       // Delete from main context
                       for (MyEntity *entity in self.entities) {
                           if ([idEntity integerValue] == [entity.idEntity integerValue]) {
                               [mainContext deleteObject:entity];
                               break;
                            }
                       }

                       // Delete from private context
                       for (MyEntity *entity in self.tempEntities) {
                           if ([idEntity integerValue] == [entity.idEntity integerValue]) {
                               [self.privateContext deleteObject:entity];
                               break;
                            }
                       }
                   }
               }
           }

           if (toModify.count > 0) {
               // Get main context
               NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext = [CoreDataStack getMainContext];

               if (mainContext != nil) {
                   for (NSNumber *idEntity in toModify) {

                    // Delete from main context
                    for (MyEntity *entity in self.entities) {
                        if ([idEntity integerValue] == [entity.idEntity integerValue]) {
                               [mainContext deleteObject:entity];
                               break;
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
           }

           [self saveContext:self.privateContext];
           [self clearContext:self.privateContext];
       }
   }
}
```

After this method, I refetch data in `mainContext`. I run the app and this seemed to work but... is it actually "legal" what I'm doing? Could I get errors and crashes other times I run the app?

If that is the case, that I'm doing wrong, how could I manage this scenario? The services I call for updates are asynchronous, and I need to wait for their responses and then create the new objects with the information I get. Then compare with the objects I already had. I can't perform updates directly on objects I already have.

Thanks

Comment: Why you don't update existing objects instead of creating new ones?

Comment: @kirander because services only give to me the objects that need to be updated. I mean: if I receive a certain object with the flag "isValid" set to false, that means I have to delete the corresponding object I had. For the rest of the objects I receive from the service, if they were already present in the app I need to update their attributes with the new ones, and if they weren't already present, I need to insert them. So I need to get the complete response of the services in order to know what changes I have to apply.

Comment: @kirander maybe I could update objects one by one while parsing the services responses, though that sounds worse regarding performance... I posted another question regarding this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32805731/best-approach-to-update-managed-objects-from-async-web-services-responses

Comment: It should be some identifier on object. Than you can fetch only object with this identifier and update, delete or if there is no any - create.